# Phabricator - folder structure of repositories

Tags: repository, gitolite, phabricator

I have 300 local repositories managed with gitolite. The folder structure of repositories on the version control server looks like this:

```
folder1/folder2/repo1.git
folder1/folder2/repo2.git
folder1/folder3/repo3.git
folder1/repo4.git
```

If the repository name is: folder1/folder2/repo5.git than the repository will go in folder1/folder2/  and so on.

In Phabricator you have one folder with all the repositories.

How can I structure the repositories in Phabricator to be in more folders?

Comment: why would you need control about how Phabricator organizes the Repos internally?

Answer (score 1):

on http://phab.example.com/diffusion/CALLSIGN/edit/storage/ you can see that the storage location can be changed via command line ala

```
phabricator/ $ ./bin/repository edit CALLSIGN --as user --local-path ...
```

Comment: mnagel thanks for the answer! Unfortunately in this way you can not keep them under control. gitolite is doing that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a folder structure where I managed categories of repositories in subfolders. As several script we created still need this folder structure, we wrote an additional bash script... This script walks through all the folders. For each git repository, a callsign is generated and a conduit call is sent to phabricator to create a regarding diffusion repo.
If we create new repos, we first create the git repository itself and let afterwards our additional script create the diffusion repo.
I can also post that script if you are interested in.

Here comes the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dryrun="false"
overwrite="false"


if [ $# = 1 ]; then
  if [ $1 = "dryrun" ]; then
    dryrun="true"
  fi
  if [ $1 = "overwrite" ]; then
    overwrite="true"
  fi
fi

folders_cat_a=(/var/git/folder1 /var/git/folder2 /var/git)
folders_cat_b=(/var/git/folder3 /var/git/folder4 /var/git/folder5)

CALLSIGNS=()

# PHIDs:
# Project A+B
phidAB="PHID-PLCY-wbdhp4lpqhm4so7qafaj"
# Project A
phidA="PHID-PROJ-vcfjz6kvjqqec2szdgno"
# Project B
phidB="PHID-PROJ-jjezy3xb6cbbwdshoihm"

# little method to check whether or not an array contains a dedicated element
containsElement () {
  local e
  for e in "${@:2}"; do [[ "$e" == "$1" ]] && return 0; done
  return 1
}

createPhabricatorRepo () {

  # for all *.git sub folders in the passed folder
  for i in $( ls $1 | grep '\.git$'); do

    # build the repository name and callsign from the folder name
    name=$(sed 's|.git||g' <<< $i)

    # remove '-'
    callsign=$(sed 's|-||g' <<< $i)
    # remove '_'
    callsign=$(sed 's|_||g' <<< $callsign)
    # replace 'vXXX'
    callsign=$(sed 's|v000||g' <<< $callsign)
    callsign=$(sed 's|v100|ONE|g' <<< $callsign)
    callsign=$(sed 's|v200|TWO|g' <<< $callsign)
    # remove '.git'
    callsign=$(sed 's|.git||g' <<< $callsign)
    #replace any remaining numbers
    callsign=$(sed 's|[0-9]|X|g' <<< $callsign)
    # to uppercase
    callsign=${callsign^^}

    # test whether callsign already exists, append an additional letter if it exists
    if containsElement "$callsign" "${CALLSIGNS[@]}"; then
      for j in {B..Z};
      do
        if ! containsElement "$callsign$j" "${CALLSIGNS[@]}"; then
          callsign=$callsign$j
          break
        fi
      done
    fi

    # add callsign to array
    CALLSIGNS+=($callsign)

    if [ $dryrun = "false" ]; then

      if [ $overwrite = "true" ]; then
        /var/phabricator/scripts/destroy-by-monogram.sh r$callsign
      fi

      echo '{
      "name":"'$name'",
      "clone-name":"'$name'",
      "callsign":"'$callsign'",
      "vcs":"git",
      "encoding":"UTF-8",
      "hosting-enabled":true,
      "serve-over-http":"off",
      "serve-over-ssh":"readwrite",
      "viewPolicy":"'$phidAB'",
      "editPolicy":"admin",
      "pushPolicy":"'$2'",
      "allow-dangerous-changes":true,
      "localPath":"'$1'/'$i'"}' | arc call-conduit repository.create | grep -v "ERR-DUPLICATE"

    else

      echo $1/$i
      echo "name: "$name
      echo "callsign: "$callsign
      echo ""

    fi

  done

}

for folder in ${folders_cat_a[@]}; do
  createPhabricatorRepo $folder $phidA
done

for folder in ${folders_cat_b[@]}; do
  createPhabricatorRepo $folder $phidB
done
```

Please note, that I extended phabricators conduit api to be able to pass the policies, allow-dangerous-changes and the clone-name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please post the script? I will like to have a look at it, even if it's still a complicated way of doing this in Phabricator compare with gitolite.